# Spring batch complex conditional flow not working

Tags: spring-batch

I want to run a 3 steps spring batch job juste like this :

- run step1
- if step1 returns COMPLETED exit status then run step2
- else fail the job
- if step2 returns COMPLETED exit status then run step3
- else fail the job
- if step3 returns COMPLETED exit status then end the job
- else fail the job

I implemented my need like this :

```
.start(step1())
    .on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).fail()
    .on(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode()).to(step2())
.from(step2())
    .on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).fail()
    .on(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode()).to(step3())
.from(step3())
    .on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).fail()
    .on(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode()).end()
```

All the three steps are nominale steps composed of a reader, a processor and writer. step 1 and 2 are writing into database and step 3 to a file, and all step listeners are returning the COMPLETED exit code (`org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus#COMPLETED`)

```
    private Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Step1InClass, Step1OutClass>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
                .reader(step1Reader())
                .processor(step1Processor)
                .writer(step1Writer)
                .listener(step1Writer)
                .listener(step1StepListener)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .build();
    }

    private Step step2() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .<Step2InClass, Step2OutClass>chunk(1)
                .reader(step2Reader())
                .processor(step2Processor())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skip(Exception.class)
                .skipLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .writer(step2Writer)
                .listener(step2Writer)
                .listener(step2StepListener)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .build();
    }

    private Step step3() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step3")
                .<step3InClass, step3OutClass>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
                .reader(step3Reader())
                .processor(step3Processor)
                .writer(step3Writer()) // a fileFlatFileItemWriter
                .listener(step3Listener)
                .listener(step3StepListener)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .build();
    }
```

This runs only step1 and step2 but not step3 !

Comment: please share console log

Comment: and step3 definition

Comment: @WoAiNii I provided more detail about steps in the question body

Comment: Your flow definition is correct, I tried it here: https://gist.github.com/benas/e51516e63580e505bc6610e8d3e61523. So if step3 is not executed, this means the exit status of step2 is set to FAILED somewhere (either the step failed or one of its listeners is setting its exit status to FAILED).

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine (sorry for the delay) I've checked the exit status, it is set by the step2 listener to COMPLETED but the step3 is not started :/ maybe it is something specific to my job or steps that I havent found yet - anyway thanks for your comment

Comment: @medmoufahim were you able to figure out the issue?